# C# Write Listview, and Read Listview (how to add indicator for listview for subitem)

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I got this project going on for myself to keep some thing in order.

What I have is this:

```
+---Date---+----Time----+----Error-----------+
|24-24-2012|    4:42    | Warning - test/test|
+----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Now I got all that working, at least the reading & writing. but its not going as I was hoping it would.

I wanted these text to be like:

```
Date (items.add)
time (subitem)
error (subitem)
```

I want it to be written like:

```
date | time | error
```

and then once the program read it, he knows:

```
| = Start of subitem ( || end of subitem )
```

so what it would look like in the text file to be written to is:

```
date | time ||| error || ( which means : time start+end / error start+end (add to subitem)
```

I want the program visual studio to know that he knows that `( | 1x = subitems.add(" - And | 2x = ");`

ugh quite hard to explain. I'll try less complicated.

```
| = subitems.add("<br>
|| = ");
```

so writing a file would look like :

```
writer.writeline( | + "hello" + || + | + "test" + || );
```

which will result in the text file as :

```
| hello ||| test ||
```

Once program boots up, it will read it again this way:

```
Listview.additems.add( hello ) *with no | or ||*
```

and the test will be :

```
listview.subitem( test ) *with no | or ||*
```

And so on...

---

Screenshots to explain it a little bit better for someone with autism like me.

> [Click here for screenshot](http://i48.tinypic.com/2uti9vb.jpg)

Comment: Can you put some effort into making this readable?

Comment: attached a screenshot for you, hopefully that makes sense.

trying my best to explain but this is so hard for me to explain lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So adding the response as another answer.
You're code will look something like this:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(logFileName))
{
  StringBuilder currentItem = new StringBuilder();
  char currentChar;
  while (true)
  {
    if (reader.Peek() == 'specialChar')
    {
      if (currentChar == '|')
      {
        // This indicates that the currentItem is subItem
        AddNewSubitem(currentItem.ToString());
      }
      else
      {
        AddNewItem(currentItem.ToString());
      }
      currentItem.Clear();
      reader.Read();
    }
    else if (reader.Peek() != null)
    {
      curentItem.Append(reader.Read());
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you need to achieve, but what I understood I think is that you want each item in the listbox to follow a specific template - so the main one will be in some X template, and the subitems will have a different template - a bit intended.
So when addig - to the listbox depending on the item type you're adding set the

listboxitem.template = isSubitem?subItemTemplate:mainItemTemplate;

And that's all what I understood from your question.
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: err.. i wanted like... uhm

@item@@ = main
|subitem|| = subitem

i have no idea how to do this nor explain. Yet i do really want to know how

Comment: *forgot :

i dont know how to make the c# program to make it read like the following order : main - subitem - subitem.

i think thats the best subcribition i can give

Comment: actually thinking about your requirements - why you're introducing the new types of separators "|" and "||" ? Because a single line in your case contains all the info, and it's just a matter of splitting it with '|' character and taking the first item in that array as the main, and the two subsequent as subitems - what's the point of introducing those differnet types of separators ?

Comment: the | and || are the sperators of the subitem writtin in my .LOG file, i want the program to read these so he doesnt confuse it becouse all in my .LOG file is in 1 line... i dont want like 3lines to do : date-time-error, i wanted to be all that in one line, but in 1mainItem and 2in that 1mainItem as subitem

Comment: OK, so I assume you'r algorithm should work like the following. Read word by word. After reading the word - depending what characters are coming, decide what the word was - either subitem, or mainitem. If that was a minitem maintain the referce to it or the listbox item created for it, so the next read subitems will know thich listbox item they should relate to.Does this make sense ?

Comment: yea, sounds alright iam just questioning how exactly to do it.

i do have coding expierence, but then iam more looking at packet parsers and so on

perhaps, you can make me a checklist what-to / how-to?